# RegEx: possibility to use ^ in [] as beginning of input?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regex pattern to match at the beginning of input or there is not a word character.

I planed to use this pattern... but ^ only negates \W.

```
var pattern = /[^\W]s=/;
```

Is there maybe a workaround?

Comment: You have to use `/(^|\W)` - the "^" character has a different meaning inside `[ ]`.

Comment: It seems like Pointy's pattern is a good start, but without the appropriate code, that might not be enough. Please provide some test cases and the code you have so far.

Comment: In the beginning? Why `[^\W]` instead of `[\W^]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unicode representation of the character, `005E`, such as in:

```
/[\u005E\W]s=/i
```

See it online at https://regex101.com/r/X9msjq/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/zetxek/btmpo08f/

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `^` character by prefixing it with a `\`.

```
^[\^\W]s=
```

However, the preceding is *redundant*. `\W` (with a capital) matches any "non-word characters", meaning it will match anything that isn't `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`. So it will already match a `^` since it isn't a word character.

If you always want to match one `^` at the beginning, take it out of the square brackets. Since you'd only have the `\W` left inside the square brackets, you can also remove them entirely:

```
^\^\Ws=
```

Here's a working example

```js
// match ^ then a non-word character then s=
console.log('^-s='.match(/^\^\Ws=/));
```

Comment: Isn’t `[\W]` equivalent to `\W`?